# The proper way of hiding and showing Android Views?

Tags: java, android, view, show-hide, alpha

I'm creating an app and I wonder what the proper way to hide and show a View is? I've seen many saying that changing the alpha value for the View will hide it, but will it stop reacting to clicks then?
Because, in reality, something that is transparent can still be touched, like glass. These are just thoughts, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show/hide a `View` programmatically you can use `setVisibility(int visibility)`.

The `visibility` parameter can be:

- `View.VISIBLE` - shows the `View`.
- `View.GONE` - hides the `View` and recalculates the layout.
- `View.INVISIBLE` - hides the `View`, but still leaves/occupies its space in the layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setVisibility` method of View.

to show view

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to hide view

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) for more information.